# Writing files over network on another machine

Tags: linux, network-shares, symbolic-link, hardlink, junction

I have the following scenario:

- CentOS machine which downloads files (e.g., wget, or any software that tries to save to local disk)
- Ubuntu machine which contains the storage for the downloaded files (not LAN, with public IP 11.22.33.44)
- CentOS machine downloaders should write files directly to Ubuntu machine

What is the simplest way for achieving this, e.g., by linking a download directory on CentOS machine to a target directory on Ubuntu?

Please assume minimal prior knowledge of Linux, so if you can write exact commands, it would be appreciated by all newbies reading this.

E.g., in Windows, it would be trivial to map a new X: drive pointing to \\11.22.33.44\share\storage

Comment: Not the safest way for the public networks, however, you can create an iSCSI target on your Ubuntu server and connect it to CentOS one. https://linuxhint.com/iscsi_storage_server_ubuntu/

Comment: Please edit question and describe your network situation (both machines on LAN? Both machines on separate data centers? Something else?). The best way to do this will depend on that.

Comment: You can configure NFS or SAMBA server service on your ubuntu and mount on centos.

Comment: @Stuka, that's a possibility, but I feel there must be something simpler out there, like the equivalent of accessing a network path in Windows.

Comment: @dirkt, an IP is an IP regardless of its data center/location. Can you give me a scenario where a solution might apply in LAN but impossible in WAN? Or applicable in same data centers, but not on different data centers?

Comment: @GuBo, sure. But how?

Comment: You can use a shared network drive (Samba, NFS) in a LAN. That's not recommended for WAN. (Exercise: why not? Hint: Think about failure.). Exercise 2: What about security?

Comment: sshfs mentioned in the reply should work. I should try it myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

`sshfs` is relatively simple to use. You can install sshfs on the CentOS box using

```
 yum install fuse-sshfs
```

Then from the CentOS box you can run

```
sshfs USER@11.22.33.44:/UBUNTU_DIR_TO_SHARE /LOCAL_DIRECTORY
```

Where `USER` is the name of the user on CentOS box you log in as, `UBUNTU_DIR_TO_SHARE` is where you want the files to end up, and /LOCAL_DIRECTORY is where `wget` thinks it is saving the files.

Comment: This seems the easiest method indeed, however after calling sshfs, I get: `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`

Comment: @SysCafe What happens if you run `sudo modprobe fuse` first? Is CentOS being run in a Virtual Private Server.

Comment: `sudo modprobe fuse` doesn't have any output, and yes, apparently CentOS is a VPS. Would this pose a problem?

Comment: @SysCafe It means that it may not be running the standard CentOS kernel, and you won't have any control over the kernel. It seems like sshfs isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

If ubuntu and centos are located different LANs/location, you have to create VPN connection (openvpn, ipsecvpn or wireguard) between two LANs.

OpenVPN configuration how to: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/

Step by step configuration of NFS: https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7

Why do you want to use another Linux to download data, instead of downloading data directly to Ubuntu?